# How can I convert a 24-bit image to a 16-bit rgb565 bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have an application in which the user usually loads 24-bit bitmaps. I need to save the images in a 16-bit rgb565 format. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: See http://www.go4answers.com/Example/24-bit-bmp-rgb565-file-conversion-92818.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The thread on go4answers does not include authors details on each answer and it is identical to an MSDN forum thread so I suspect that it is a blatant copy of this MSDN thread: [24 bit bmp to rGB565 file conversion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1cab307d-2f5a-489f-8653-f5a9e86a6146/24-bit-bmp-to-rgb565-file-conversion?forum=csharpgeneral). The MSDN thread also has more answers and more discussion, so I'd use it in preference to the go4answers one Liviu M recommends in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4131549/575530). I have no idea why [Google prefers the go4answers copy over the MSDN original](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=c%23+bitmap+rgb565), hopefully that'll change.

Just to summarise a few of the points covered in [the MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1cab307d-2f5a-489f-8653-f5a9e86a6146/24-bit-bmp-to-rgb565-file-conversion?forum=csharpgeneral).

1. Try the [FormatConvertedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx) class. It uses the [PixelFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.aspx) class to specify the format of the resulting conversion. One of the predefined pixel formats defined by the PixelFormats class is [BGR565](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.bgr565(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. You'll notice that "BGR" != "RGB" and the thread includes discussion of the swapped colors. So another answer there recommends the classic [System.Drawing.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.aspx) namespace and its [PixelFormat enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) which includes the member `Format16bppRgb565`

The discussion of the red/blue swap is fairly lengthy (useful bug, by design, problem, not a problem, ...) and seems to reach the conclusion that PixelFormats.Bgr565 is in fact in RGB565.